# conda activate envs failed, how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

First, create a new environment:

```
conda create -name AI python=3.12
```

And then:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBST6.png)

The environment is created successfully! However fail to activate the created environment!

The method in the website is useless for me!

Comment: You are using powershell (see the `PS` in the beginning), which has some extra steps required. If you are using VS Code (or some other IDE), switch your terminal to normal command prompt (cmd) and your commands should work just fine.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to show terminal content.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this:

```
cd <parent_folder_for_env>
conda create --prefix=<env_name> python=3.12

.... confirm the transaction

conda activate .\<env_name>
```

This should work I have just tested it.

**EDIT:**

If this does not work for you you should probably reinstall miniconda.

Note that you must not have another Python installed and set in Path env. variable, this will 100% lead to collision and cause you nothing but problems.